# I keep getting file upload errors in my multisite Drupal Installation when I try to add a photo for my user avatar

Tags: apache, drupal, file-upload

keep getting the following error when I try to upload an image for my user profile:

```
The specified file temporary://picture-1-1366485906.jpg could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log
```

I have a multsite installation meaning I have the following:

```
sites/domain1.com
sites/domain2.com
sites/domain3.com
```

It is not happening on the first domain, but on domains 2 and 3 it is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to file system url of each website & make sure details are saved there properly.

Example:
http://domain2.com/admin/settings/file-system